# Upsert into table using Merge for Scala for Scala using Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, scala, databricks, azure-databricks

With Databricks Delta Table you can upsert data from a source table, view, or DataFrame into a target Delta table using the merge operation. This operation is similar to the SQL MERGE INTO command but has additional support for deletes and extra conditions in updates, inserts, and deletes.

I can successfully carryout a Merge using the following Python code:

```
from delta.tables import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, delta_path)

(deltaTable
  .alias("t")
  .merge(loanUpdates.alias("s"), "t.loan_id = s.loan_id")
  .whenMatchedUpdateAll()
  .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
  .execute())
```

However, I need to use Scala. Therefore, can someone provide the code that will do the same in Scala. Basically, I help converting the Python code Scala.

There are examples provided here, https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#language-scala however I would like to able to use the Python code above

Comment: I took a stab at it myself with the following code ```%scala

val loanUpdates = "/FileStore/tables/loanUpdates.csv"

import io.delta.tables._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, loanUpdates)

deltaTable
  .as("t")
  .merge(
    loanUpdates.as("s"),
    "t.loan_id = s.loan_id")
  .whenNotMatched()
  .insertAll()
  .execute()```

Comment: But I get the following error: ```command-4074064246622552:12: error: value as is not a member of String
    loanUpdates.as("s"),```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, loanUpdates is a string, but it needs to be a Dataframe. You can load a CSV into Spark using:

`val loanUpdatesDf = spark.read.csv(loanUpdates)`

You will probably need to use further options to read the csv correctly.

Comment: I tried the following with your suggestion ```val loanUpdates = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/loanUpdates.csv")

val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, loanUpdates)

deltaTable
  .as("t")
  .merge(
    loanUpdates.as("s"),
    "t.loan_id = s.loan_id")
  .whenNotMatched()
  .insertAll()
  .execute()```

Comment: But I get the following error: ```command-4074064246622552:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: String
val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, loanUpdates)```

Comment: AT the moment you're trying to upsert from loanTables into loanTables -> you need to feed a string into `DeltaTable.forPath(spark, <STRING GOES HERE>)`, but on the merge it needs to be a  DataFrame , i.e. `.merge(MUST_BE_DATAFRAME.alias("s")`